# AdMob. Is it possible to keep screen bright while InterstitialAd is showing?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm using [AdMob plugin](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/tree/master/unity) for Android game on Unity3d. Whereas I can keep screen bright during game session, I can't control phone behaviour during InterstitialAd showing - screen become dim and get locked.

I tryed to modify Interstitial.java class to set FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON or set WAKELOCK for activity but get nothing.

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(activity);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
  ...

  @Override
  public void onAdOpened() {         
      // this not worked!
      PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
      PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
      wakeLock.acquire();

      // this not worked too
      activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

      adListener.onAdOpened();
  }
});
```

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I found solution.

In short: WAKE_LOCK is worked if used with flags `PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP`. Without them screen will go to sleep.

Full code:

```
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
            "com.google.unity.ads.Interstitial"
    );

    InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(activity);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAdLoaded() {
        isLoaded = true;
        adListener.onAdLoaded();
      }

      @Override
      public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        adListener.onAdFailedToLoad(PluginUtils.getErrorReason(errorCode));
      }

      @Override
      public void onAdOpened() {
        wakeLock.acquire();
        adListener.onAdOpened();
      }

      @Override
      public void onAdClosed() {
        adListener.onAdClosed();
        wakeLock.release();
      }

      @Override
      public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        adListener.onAdLeftApplication();
      }
    });
```

Of course, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` should be defined somewhere in AndroidManifest.

**Warning:** In this code wakelock is not released if application going to background, so if user collapsed application while ad is showing, CPU still be working and screen will be bright all time until app will be closed completely or will be opened and interstitial ad will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try put this code into AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but problem is much more deeper than just missing permission in manifest.